# Textmate Grammar - Highlight 'STR$' call

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate

I had this regex for capturing some standard lib calls in a TextMate (vs code) grammar:

`(?i)\b(sin|cos|tan)\b`

Now, in a call like `str$(5)`, I'd like to capture `str$`. You can't do:

`(?i)\b(sin|cos|tan|str\$)\b`

Because of the ending word boundary (I think?)

I tried

`(?i)\b(sin|cos|tan|str\$)( |\()`

But that causes:

[image: wrongBracketHighlighting]

Can you capture a word with a special character on the end & word boundaries either side (without "capturing" the actual chars on the boundaries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)\b(sin|cos|tan|str\$)(?!\w)
                         ^^^^^^
```

Or

```
(?i)(?<!\w)(sin|cos|tan|str\$)(?!\w)
    ^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

The `(?!\w)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a letter, digit or an underscore.

The `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind that will fail the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a letter, digit or an underscore.

Comment: Thanks for explaining them too!